# Conditional `echo` (or eval or include) in rmarkdown chunks

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to create an Rmarkdown document (pdf or html) that has some chunks "executed" conditionally.  The particular case I have in mind is that I might want a more verbose and documented version of the output for internal review by colleagues, and a shorter version for external consumers.  I may not want or need to show data manipulation steps to a client, but just key graphs and tables.  I also do not want to make two separate documents or have to manually indicate what to show or not.

Is there a way to set a switch at the beginning of the Rmd that indicates, e.g., verbose=T that will run all chunks or verbose=F that toggles echo=F (or include=F)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

knitr options can be stated as R expressions. Per [the "output" documentation on the knitr webpage](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/):

> Note all options in knitr can take values from R expressions, which brings the feature of conditional evaluation introduced in the main manual. In short, `eval=dothis` means the real value of eval is taken from a variable named `dothis` in the global environment; by manipulating this variable, we can turn on/off the evaluation of a batch of chunks.

In other words if you write some chunks like:

````
```{r label}
doNextChunk <- as.logical(rbinom(1,1,.5))
```

```{r conditional, eval = doNextChunk}
"hello world!"
```
````

Comment: This set me on track.  I am setting a variable `draft <-TRUE` at the beginning of the document.  It takes on `FALSE` for a production run.  Then, in any chunk I want to be able to turn on or off display, I add `include=draft` to all specific chunks I want to be able to toggle.  Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to somehow change the chunk label this way as well?

Comment: Also, is it possible to pass the argument as a parameter using render (i.e., to specify doNextChunk as an argument when using render)?

Answer (score 2):

`opts_chunk$set()`  is what you are after. Anything "set" will be the default for subsequent chunks (unless overwritten on a chunk-by-chunk basis)

`````
```{r setup}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(eval = TRUE, include= TRUE)
````
`````

You can then alter as you see fit.