# knitr: conditionally evaluate normal chunks

Tags: r, knitr

Here's what I'd like to do, in my Rhtml document:

```
<!--begin.rcode
if (errors==1) {
end.rcode-->
<p>You have an error!</p>
<!--begin.rcode

end.rcode-->
```

Basically, I'm trying to use knitr like PHP. The above doesn't work, but is there a right way to do it?

This question is different from [Conditional `echo` (or eval or include) in rmarkdown chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354903/conditional-echo-or-eval-or-include-in-rmarkdown-chunks). That is about how to conditionally evaluate a knitr "chunk". This is about how to conditionally evaluate the "normal" HTML (or TeX, or Markdown) in between two knitr chunks.

Comment: If you do not insist using `knitr`, then you might give a try to `pander` with `<% ... %>` tags for conditionals and `<%= ... %>` for printing markdown: http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#brew-to-pandoc, otherwise you might want to `brew::brew` your document before passing to `knitr`. Or maybe there's an internal `knitr` support for this, I'm not sure :)

Comment: Try putting your HTML (or TeX or md) in a `cat` statement in a conditionally evaluated chunk.

Comment: @dash2 my above comment is still valid after your edit

Comment: @daroczig yes, `brew` is one way to go. But I would like to know if there is a `knitr` solution.

Comment: @Thomas see my comment on arvi1000's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a normal `if` block in the chunk. If you want an HTML formatted error message, you can use `results='asis'` in the chunk options. Like this:

```
<!--begin.rcode results='asis'
if (errors==1) {
  cat('<p>You have an error</p>')
} else {
  # r code to evaluate when errors!=1
}
end.rcode-->
```

Comment: This is true and useful, but it isn't what I am looking for. One can print out HTML from within R, but for large blocks of HTML it is nicer and more readable to have them directly in the file.

Comment: A recourse would be to park the large html block in 'other_source_file.html', then readLines + cat to get the content. Not the exact procedure you are asking about, but preserves easy reading/editing. I'm not optimistic the exact thing you are asking about is possible, but let's see what others say.