# rmarkdown: manipulate chunk options programmatically?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Is it possible to take an rmarkdown file, programmatically manipulate chunk options, and then `knit` based on the modified document?

I have some rmarkdown files that I want to `purl`, with all code (even ones with `eval=FALSE`) included.

At this point, my best guess is that I could (1) use `sed` to switch `eval=FALSE` to `eval=TRUE`, and then (2) `purl`. But I'd love if there's something nicer, for example maybe like:

```
parsed_rmd <- knitr::parse_rmd('my_rmarkdown.rmd')
for (chunk in parsed_rmd) {
 chunk$eval <- TRUE
}
knitr::purl(parsed_rmd, output = 'my_rmarkdown_as_r.R'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional \`echo\` (or eval or include) in rmarkdown chunks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354903/conditional-echo-or-eval-or-include-in-rmarkdown-chunks)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That question says "Is there a way to set a switch at the beginning of the Rmd..." - my question is not asking about modifying the `Rmd` file, but how to manipulate the processing of an `Rmd` file that I'm not free to modify.

Comment: If the Rmd had variables in those places (like eval=doEval) then you probably could do `eval <- FALSE; knit("file.Rmd")` Without changing the Rmd file further. Would that work?

Comment: I don't want to have to change the `Rmd` files.

Comment: But aren't you also changing it with `sed` ? What you seem to require is a way to set global value for `eval` and then forbid that value from being changed again locally at each chunk. I am not sure if that's possible but maybe someone else can comment on that.

Comment: Right, I'll change it with `sed` in a tempfile if I have to. What I definitely don't want to do is change it manually. (If I have to change it with `sed`, I think I might as well just have `eval=TRUE` in my tempfile rather than your `eval=doEval`.)

Answer (score 6):

You can set the 'eval' chunk option to a logical condition based on a parameter.

Create an Rmarkdown (.Rmd) file and define the parameter in the YAML header:

```
params:
     eval_optional: no
```

Set the 'eval' option for the code chunk you may not want to show to test the value of this parameter:

````
```{r optional_code, eval= (params$eval_optional == "Yes")}
# chunk with code you only want to show sometimes
```
````

Then call `rmarkdown_render` with the appropriate parameter:

```
rmarkdown::render(file = "myreport.rmd", params = list(eval_optional = "yes")
```

See http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html for more on using parameters